# Code error in a SQL Server While-If Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, while-loop

I know that there are other posts with code that solve my problem but I don't want to take another's code so I'm trying to do it by myself and I'm stuck with the month not increasing problem, so if anyone can help me with that mistake it will be awesome.

The problem is:

I have to populate the table Time from year 1990 to 2016 with all the months and days, I have already achieved that the code works and it populates correctly the years and the days but months increases to January (1) and  then is not increasing so the table is filled with all months being January (LOL)

Here's my code:

```
create table Time
(
    Year int, 
    Month int,
    Day int
)

create procedure pTime
as
    declare @year int, @month int, @day int;
    set @year = 1990;
    set @month = 12;
    set @day = 10;

while(@year<=2016)
Begin

    If(@day = 29)
    Begin

        set @month = @month + 1;

        If(@month = 13)
        Begin

            set @month = 1;
            set @day = 1;
            set @year = @year + 1;

            insert into Time values (@year, @month, @day);
        End
    End 

    else
    Begin
        If(@day = 29)
        Begin

            set @month = @month + 1;
            set @day = 1;

            insert into Time values (@year, @month, @day);
        End

        Else    
        Begin

            insert into Time values (@year, @month, @day);

            set @day = @day + 1;
        End
    End
End
```

Any idea where is my mistake or any suggestion?

Comment: "Please debug my code" kind of questions are not particularly welcome here. I think your approach to solve the problem is not very efficient. I would rather use a date data type and the DateAdd function. - But as you want to pursue your own approach, take a long hard look at the If(@year = 29) condition.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Let me correct it. Thanks :)
I don't want the community to debug my code, I just looking for some hint of what I'm missing, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look very closely for your mistake because SQL Server has some helpful date arithmetic functions.  Here's simplified version of your stored procedure:

```
create procedure pTime
as
  declare @theDate date = '12/10/1990', @days int = 0

while @theDate < '1/1/2016'
  begin
    insert into Time (Year, Month, Day) values (datepart(year, @theDate), datepart(month, @theDate), datepart(day, @theDate));
    set @theDate = dateadd(day, 1, @theDate)
  end
```

Comment: You are a f@ckin' GOD. This is what I was talking about, not debugging my code, just giving me hints about how to do it. You are really awesome, dude. I'm going to study this code. Thanks a lot, dude :D

Comment: Thanks for the praise and you're welcome.  Feel free to ask if you have questions.  Please accept the answer if it does work out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Another faster approach would be to use a tally table. Note the code below:

```
WITH
E(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1 FROM E a,E b,E c,E d,E e),
dates(dt) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP(datediff(DAY,'19900101','20160101')) DATEADD(day,N,'19900101') 
  FROM iTally
)
--INSERT [time] --uncomment for the insert, leave commented to see what will be inserted
SELECT YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt), DAY(dt)
FROM dates;
```

Comment: This is the fastest way compare with other answers

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `If(@year = 29)` condition? In your code this block never will be executed. try this:

```
create procedure pTime
as
    declare @year int, @month int, @day int;
    set @year = 1990;
    set @month = 12;
    set @day = 10;

while(@year<=2016)
Begin
    If(@day = 29)
    Begin

        set @month = @month + 1;
        set @day = 1;

        If(@month = 13)
        Begin
            set @month = 1;            
            set @year = @year + 1;
            insert into Time values (@year, @month, @day);
        End
    End 

    else
    Begin
        If(@day = 29)
        Begin

            set @month = @month + 1;
            set @day = 1;

            insert into Time values (@year, @month, @day);
        End

        Else    
        Begin

            insert into Time values (@year, @month, @day);

            set @day = @day + 1;
        End
    End
End
```

I think first assignment  `set @day = 1;` wasn't in right place. After increasing `@month` value you should set also `@day` to 1;

Comment: That was my mistake writing my code here, i hav edited the post to correct it.

Comment: HA! Thanks bro, I didn't notice about that (i feel kinda dumb, lol). You are really awesome too :D